# How to use Java 8 Stream API for filter the list within a set

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

```
class A {
    List<B> b;
}

class B{
    boolean flag;

    B(boolean flag) {
        this.flag = flag;
    }
    //getter setter
}

B b1 = new B(true);
B b2 = new B(true);
B b3 = new B(false);

List<B> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
list1.add(b1);
list1.add(b2);
list1.add(b3);

Set<A> a = new HashSet<>();
a.add(list1);
```

There is a set of object A.

Object A contains a list of object B. B has a boolean property name 'flag'
Using java 8 streams API, how to filter the set above such that it contains the list of B with boolean flag as true only.
i.e b3 should be removed from list1.
To keep it simple just added the single value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a class `A` that contains a list of `B`; the goal is to remove, in each `A`, all the `B` that matches a condition.

The first solution is make a stream of the set of `A`s and map each of them to a new `A` where the list of `B` was filtered. Assuming that there is a constructor `A(List<B> b)` and the appropriate getters (`List<B> getB()` in class `A`; `boolean isFlag()` in class `B`), you could have:

```
Set<A> set = new HashSet<>();

Set<A> filtered =
    set.stream()
       .map(a -> new A(a.getB().stream().filter(B::isFlag).collect(Collectors.toList())))
       .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

A second solution is possible if you can modify the list of `B`s in-place, instead of creating a new one. In such a case, you could have:

```
set.forEach(a -> a.getB().removeIf(b -> !b.isFlag()));
```

which will remove all `B` where the flag is `false` for each `A`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    @org.junit.Test
    public void test() {
        B b1 = new B(true);
        B b2 = new B(true);
        B b3 = new B(false);

        List<B> list1 = new ArrayList();
        list1.add(b1);
        list1.add(b2);
        list1.add(b3);

        Set<A> a = new HashSet();
        a.add(new A(list1));

        a.stream().forEach(aa -> aa.setB(aa.getB().stream().filter(B::isFlag).collect(Collectors.toList())));

        System.out.println(a);
    }
```

output:

```
[A{b=[B{flag=true}, B{flag=true}]}]
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Ok, I will remember that and promise to improve :)

Answer (score 0):

```
a.stream().forEach(l -> l.removeIf(b -> !b.getFlag()));
```

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.